# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ilegal value, when I try to pass object via bundle

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

I'm trying to pass an object from the class "Transfer" (java) to the class "Limit" (Kotlin), if I try to get the values ​​that come through the "Bundle" using data.name, the compiler does not give an error, but when I enter in the activity of this problem, how can I get an object via Bundle () in my intent?

```
public class Transfer {
    
    private void sendBundle(){
        Usermodel doTransfer = fillUserModel();
        Limit.intentTransfer(doTransfer, "France");
    }
    
    
    private UserModel fillUserModel() {
        Usermodel newUserModel = new Usermodel();
        usermodel.setName("Jonas");
        userModel.setAge("30");
        usermodel.setIdNumber("123458");
        userModel.setOccupation("dev");
        userModel.setFormation("CC");
        
        return newUserModel ;
    }

}
```

```
class UserModel(

    val name: String? = "",
    val age: String? ="",
    val idNumber: String? ="",
    val occupation: String? ="",
    val formation: String? ="",
)
```

```
class Limit {

     private val data: Usermodel by bindBundle(DATA)

     private val country: String by bindBundle(COUNTRY)

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

      //here I can get the values ​​using  data.name or data.age 
      //  and android studio does not point out error

}


companion object {
  
    const val DATA = "data"
    const val COUNTRY= "CountryUser"
}


fun intentTransfer (test : UserModel, CountryUser : String)
 : Intent {
        return Intent(context, Limit::class.java).apply {
            putExtras(
                BundleOf(
                    DATA to test,
                    COUNTRY to CountryUser 
                )
            )
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT
WHEN I ENTER ACTIVITY:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Ilegal value type android.model.UserModel for key "data"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to make the class `Parcelable` whose object you are passing through the `Bundle`.

In your gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
```

Your data class should be like:

```
@Parcelize
data class UserModel(

    val name: String? = "",
    val age: String? ="",
    val idNumber: String? ="",
    val occupation: String? ="",
    val formation: String? ="",
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: `@Parcelize` is no longer experimental

Answer (score 3):

Your `UserModel` class cannot be recognized by bundle as a Serializable or Parcelable. Try to implement one of them and error will disappear.

Comment: Alexander, thanks for the reply, I will implement and give you feedback.

Comment: for serializable just `class UserModel: Serializable`

Answer (score 3):

I spent half day with this issue. My app crashed with same error.
But I use kotlinx.serialization annotations and could not even imagine that I need additionally mention about Serialization
Even AS can see this parameter as Serializable!
Just added `java.io.Serializable` to the code and fixed[image]